# Найти индекс элемента списка

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно найти индекс элемента списка, где текст "На связи".
как это сделать на js?

попробовал сделать так, но оно не работает

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.t-BadgeList-item');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i];
  var label = item.querySelector('.t-BadgeList-label').textContent;
  if (label.trim() === 'На связи') {
    var index = i + 1;
    console.log('Номер элемента списка: ' + index);
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="t-Region-body a-Collapsible-content" id="a_Collapsible2_DASH2_content" aria-hidden="false">
  <ul class="t-BadgeList u-colors  t-BadgeList--dash  t-BadgeList--stacked ">
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><a href="#" class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">93</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">ВСЕГО</span></a></li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><a href="#" class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">91</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">АО подключено</span></a></li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><a href="#" class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">2</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">АО частичное отключение</span></a></li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><span class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">58</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">На связи</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><span class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">19</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">Не на связи &gt; 24ч.</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><span class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">16</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">Не на связи &gt; 7д.</span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149789/discussion-on-question-by-rsk----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

тут выведется именно индекс элемента

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.t-BadgeList-item');
const idx = Array.from(items).findIndex(el => {
    const label = el.querySelector('.t-BadgeList-label')
    return label.textContent.trim() === 'На связи'
})

console.log(idx)
```

```html
<div class="t-Region-body a-Collapsible-content" id="a_Collapsible2_DASH2_content" aria-hidden="false">
  <ul class="t-BadgeList u-colors  t-BadgeList--dash  t-BadgeList--stacked ">
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><a href="#" class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">93</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">ВСЕГО</span></a></li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><a href="#" class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">91</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">АО подключено</span></a></li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><a href="#" class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">2</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">АО частичное отключение</span></a></li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><span class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">58</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">На связи</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><span class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">19</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">Не на связи &gt; 24ч.</span></span>
    </li>
    <li class="t-BadgeList-item"><span class="t-BadgeList-wrap u-color"><span class="t-BadgeList-value ">16</span><span class="t-BadgeList-label t-BadgeList-label--bottom">Не на связи &gt; 7д.</span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```